# Where is my data located when I backup a docker container volume?

Tags: docker

I tried to run:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from DATA -v $(pwd):/backup busybox tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /data
```

Where is "/data" located? I cannot find it on my system.

Answer (score 2):

The `tar` command is executed on the container itself. In your particular case the data might be lost. That is because after the `tar` command ends, the container itself ends. And as you specified `--rm` it is deleted.

When your volume container DATA has `/data`, the data is stored there. You can access it by linking to it from an other container again like:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from DATA busybox ls /data
```